# How to set same profile settings to every user in a domain

Tags: windows-xp, active-directory, profile

I need to set the user variables and settings for every user in a domain.
The settings are:

- Advanced performance options
- visual effects for best performances

Also:

- Java Auto update option is to be disabled or unchecked
- In Internet security settings, under Download >Miscellaneous >Display Mixed content should be enable.
- User environment variable should be TEMP =E:\temp

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to implement some of these settings through Group Policy.  If you're new to GPOs, this excel docs might come in handy (you should mention which server OS you're using):

[**Group Policy Settings References for Windows and Windows Server**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en)

Your other alternative is to look at scripting these:

- [Update environment variables from the command line (Windows 2008 Server Core)](https://serverfault.com/questions/70603/update-environment-variables-from-the-command-line-windows-2008-server-core)
- [PowerShell? Do you use it? Can you show me some cool system administration things I can do with it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13493/powershell-do-you-use-it-show-me-some-cool-sysadmin-things-i-can-do-with-it)

Comment: great link for the spreadsheet...I remember having that file but lost it...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe look at group policies for user and workstation settings?

Also you could make the settings on one machine then use regedt32 to export the keys...this export could then be either ran manually on a machine or used as part of the login script?

I can try post more details if you think its a good option

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate my answer on superuser....

In a domain environment you would generally use group policy for Windows settings and customised MSI installers (deployed via group policy) to alter settings for 3rd party software such as the Java runtime.

**1.**
According to

windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/84925/jsi-tip-10021-how-can-i-set-the-windows-xp-visual-effects-to-adjust-for-best-performance-using-the-registry.html

you could run this via a logon script:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects" /V VisualFXSetting /T REG_DWORD /F /D 2
```

or set the same setting using a custom ADM in a GPO.

**2.**
There is info about making a custom Java MSI with auto update disabled here:

www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=38

**3.**
According to [the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457144.aspx) you can set that via group policy.

**4.**
You can set user environment variables in a logon script. The command required will vary depending on the scripting language you use (cmd shell/vbs/kix)

In a DOS batch file it's just:

SET TEMP=E:\Temp